# Выгружать данные при заполнении формы

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Этот код  выгружает данные из  бд по очереди при обновлении страницы, если данные закончились, он начинает сначала. Как переделать, чтобы пока форма пуста, данные не выгружались, как только форму заполнили, данные опять выгружались?

я так сделал, но при первом получении из формы не выводит, когда воторой раз из формы получил, тогда выводит

```
if($_POST['u_name']==""){
              if(isset($_COOKIE['my_record_id4'])){
                   $current_record4=(int)$_COOKIE['my_record_id4']; 
                   setcookie('my_record_id4',($current_record4),time()+3600);
                }else{
                   $current_record4=1;
                   setcookie('my_record_id4',($current_record4),time()+3600);
                };  
         }
         else{
             if(isset($_COOKIE['my_record_id4'])){
                   $current_record4=(int)$_COOKIE['my_record_id4']; 
                   setcookie('my_record_id4',($current_record4+1),time()+36000000000);
                }else{ 
                   $current_record4=1;
                   setcookie('my_record_id4',($current_record4+1),time()+36000000000);
                };
            }
            $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","%%","%%") or die("Ошибка подключения!".mysql_error());
            $s=$_COOKIE['my_record_id4']; 
            mysql_select_db("%%",$conn);
            $rezult=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM less WHERE id='.$current_record4.';',$conn);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Ваш вопрос легко решается с помощью javascript и jQuery.
2. Определите более четко что в вашем случае значит "форма заполнена". В этом Вам помогут события jquery, а именно [Form events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/) и [Keyboard Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/)

Например, событие change:

```
$( "#id_formi" ).change(function() {
 //Проверьте пуста ли форма
 //если не пуста, то ajax запрос к php файлу
});
```

3 . Сделайте из Вашего вышеуказанного кода функцию, которая возвращает $rezult

4 . Допишите проверку формы и ajax запрос:

```
    $( "#id_formi" ).change(function() {
     if ($(this).val()!= ""){  // ваша проверка на заполненность формы
         $.ajax({
            url: 'vash_php_file.php',   //путь к Вашему .php файлу с функцией
            success: function(data){
                $('#some_div').append(data); //вставить данные которые вернул ajax запрос в элемент с id some_div
            }
         });
     }
    });
```

Comment: мне через POST надо